# gzip compression at build time or runtime gzip compression with nginx?

Tags: nginx, webpack, build, gulp, gzip

Since the process of compressing a file uses CPU time, would there be any benefits of doing the gzip compression using a build tool like Gulp or Webpack, instead of doing it at runtime on the web server using nginx?

Comment: One of the benefits using Webpack would be, that you have full control how the minimization/gzipping is performed. The downside however is - you have one more thing to care about. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/compression-webpack-plugin#algorithm